# Guice injection tests fails on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, playframework-2.0, guice, sbt, jenkins-plugins

I have a strange problem with my Play 2.0.4 Java project. I am able to run all tests successfully locally using 'play clean test' or 'sbt clean test'. But when the project is built on Jenkins server using sbt-launch.jar or 'sbt clean test' a test fails because injection did not happen. Other tests not dependant on injection pass fine.

Both Jenkins and local run same version of sbt and both use Oracle Java.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show some code (the failing test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange, looks like the Jenkins job and the workspace got somehow corrupted. Recreating the job fixed this.